# Information Using VB.NET SQL STORED PROCEDURES DAL BLL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am a bit confused on what method to use when creating an application that deals with MSSQL Stored Procedures and VB.NET.

Should i study and implement the Data Access Layer along side with the Business Logic Layer? Is this approach the most efficient when needing to display data from database tables and update data also or should I be approaching this another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague, but I'll try anyway.

Yes, your data access layer should be separate from your business logic layer. It makes your code cleaner and more maintainable. 
Look into ORMs like Entity Framework for accessing your database. In some scenarios, you may not even need to write stored procedures to retrieve the data you need or perform updates.

Comment: sorry guess my question reflects on how confused I actually am. Basically I was trying to ask if you were going to create an application that needs to retrieve and update data from a MSSQL database what is the best approach. I see there are objectdatasources, sqldatasources, i read about datasets and datatables and also read about DAL and BLL alongside datasets and datatables. Just a little confused on which ones to use when approaching a project hopefully i cleared up the question some Thanks

Comment: Datasets and datatables can almost be considered legacy now for accessing data. And using objectdatasources or sqldatasources are also generally frowned upon, and should only be used for (very) rapid prototyping. Design your database carefully, then add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model to your project and add your tables to the model. Then you have 80-90% of your DAL completed.